# Co-countable topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the following exercise in my textbook:

If $T$ is an uncountable set, show that $$\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, T, \text{ all sets whose complement is at most countable\}$$

forms a topology on $T$ (the "co-countable topology").

The definition of a topology in my textbook is:

A toplogy $\mathcal{T}$ on a set $T$ is a collection of subsets of $T$, which we agree to call the 'open sets', such that

> (T1) $T$ and $\emptyset$ are open
> (T2) the finite interesection of open sets is open; and
> (T3) arbitrary unions of open sets are open.

So he is my attempt to prove this:

(T1) We can see that $T$ and $\emptyset$ are open by assumption

(T2) We have that the open sets (other than $T$ and $\emptyset$) are defined as the sets $\{U\subset T : U^c \text{ is at most countable } \}$. We know that a finite intersection of at most countable sets is countable and hence we can see that all the sets $\{V\subset T : V^c= \bigcap_{U_i\in \mathcal{T}} U_i^c \text{ is at most countable }\} \in \mathcal{T} \forall 1\leq i\lt \infty$

(T3) $\{V\subset T : V^c= \bigcup_{U_i\in \mathcal{T}} U_i^c \text{ is at most countable }\} \in \mathcal{T} \forall 1\leq i\leq \infty$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Re T2: Actually, we know that *arbitrary* intersection of countable sets is countable - so did you accidentally prove that arbitrary intersections of opens are open?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But if arbitrary intersections of sets are countable (how I interpret this is those sets $\bigcap_{i\in I} U_i$ where $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$) then surely finite intersections of sets are countable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show that the intersection of finitely many open sets $U_1, \ldots U_n$ is open, note first that we can assume WLOG that none of the $U_i$ is empty (or the intersection is empty and thus open anyway), so all $U_i^\complement$ are at most countable and then

$$(\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i)^\complement = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i^\complement$$ by de Morgan so the complement of $\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i $ is a finite union of at most countable sets so at most countable. It follows that by definition, $\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i $ is open, as required.

For the arbitrary union of sets $U_i, i \in I$ we can also assume they're all of the cocountable type (as $\emptyset$ contributes nothing to a union) and use

$$(\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i)^\complement = \bigcap_{i \in I} U_i^\complement \subseteq U_{i_0}^\complement$$ where $i_0 \in I$ is arbitrary. So the complement is also at most countable and so $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ is open by definition.